# Stripe PaymentIntents PHP, setting price

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments

Basically, the problem im having is between php and javascript, where my php function is `createPayment()` I can't put javascript variable so I can't enter the amount ($) of the order
I'm really stuck on what to do.

Maybe a post event to the server to create payment via javascript but I don't know how to do that

Javascript:

```js
document.getElementById("stripe").onclick = function(){
    const stripe = Stripe('public_key');
    const options = {
        clientSecret: "<?php include('payments.php'); $payment = createPayment(500); echo $payment->client_secret ?>",
        // Fully customizable with appearance API.
        appearance: {/*...*/},
    };

    // Set up Stripe.js and Elements to use in checkout form, passing the client secret obtained in step 2
    const elements = stripe.elements(options);

    // Create and mount the Payment Element
    const paymentElement = elements.create('payment');
    paymentElement.mount('#payment-element');   
}
```

Server side:

```php
<?php
    require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

    function createPayment($amount){
        $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient('sk_key');
        $intent = $stripe->paymentIntents->create(
            [
              'amount' => $amount,
              'currency' => 'usd',
              'automatic_payment_methods' => ['enabled' => true],
            ]
          );
        return $intent;
    };    
?>
```

Comment: it is making a request to stripe successfully and showing its elements but need help to set the price, also to mention right now, when you first go into the page it already runs that PHP code thus creating the stripe payment without them clicking document.getElementById("stripe").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## METHOD ONE

One of the ways to tackle the problem is to add an intermediate PHP (e.g. intermediate.php)

So if your original flow is

cart.php > processpayment.php (with javascript) calling payment.php to get client_secret

then change the flow to

cart.php > intermediate.php > processpayment.php(with javascript) calling payment.php to get client_secret

So for the cart.php, first call intermediate.php with a parameter of the amount, say intermediate.php?amount=1234 :

intermediate.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["amount"]=$_REQUEST["amount"]; 
header('Location: processpayment.php');
exit;
?>
```

Now in the processpayment.php

change

```
clientSecret: "<?php include('payments.php'); $payment = createPayment(500); echo $payment->client_secret ?>",
```

to

```
clientSecret: "<?php include('payments.php'); $payment = createPayment($_SESSION["amount"]); echo $payment->client_secret ?>",
```

Note: Make sure you have `<?php session_start(); ?>` at the top of processpayment.php too

## METHOD TWO # (use ajax)

An alterative is to pass the amount value (e.g. 1234) thru ajax to the server script which will return the client secret, and the use the client secret in the stripe payment processing

Hence , use the following html/js:

1. the HTML will trigger the JS function named trigger1() on window load
2. the JS trigger1() will run an ajax function, passing the amount (e.g. 1234) to server2.php and wait for the return of the client secret , then put it into a hidden input field known with ID "secret"
3. now you can get the correct client secret for the stripe payment function thru document.getElementById("secret").value, so can now just use:

```
clientSecret: document.getElementById("secret").value;
```

So , the following is the HTML/JS:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("stripe").onclick = function(){
    const stripe = Stripe('public_key');
    const options = {
        clientSecret: document.getElementById("secret").value;
        // Fully customizable with appearance API.
        appearance: {/*...*/},
    };

    // Set up Stripe.js and Elements to use in checkout form, passing the client secret obtained in step 2
    const elements = stripe.elements(options);

    // Create and mount the Payment Element
    const paymentElement = elements.create('payment');
    paymentElement.mount('#payment-element');   
}

</script>

<input type=hidden id=secret value="">

<script>
function trigger1() {
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: 'server2.php',
   data: {"amount": 1234},
   success: function (response) {
document.getElementById("secret").value=response
      },
      error: function () {
        alert("Error !!");
      }
});
}


window.onload= trigger1();

</script>
```

and use the following php (server2.php)

```
<?php
    require_once('vendor/autoload.php');


    $amount=$_GET["amount"];

        $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient('sk_key');
        $intent = $stripe->paymentIntents->create(
            [
              'amount' => $amount,
              'currency' => 'usd',
              'automatic_payment_methods' => ['enabled' => true],
            ]
          );
        
        echo $intent->client_secret;
```

Comment: That doesn't work, you are just entering a string when a number needs to be entered, I tested it anyway.

Comment: yeah we aren't putting it in strings here, php will not recognize that javascript variable, plus you are doing createPayment(" + amount +") which is just a string and will do nothing but throw a error, a number is needed. I need my javascript variable there somehow.

Comment: I don't know if its correct thing to create order in the clientsecret, but im creating it there and passing client_secret

Comment: See my revised answer

Comment: I read the new answer, I don't seem to understand how I can attach the price from javascript variable to a PHP session variable though. Also I only have the checkout page and payments.php which is only-back end.

Comment: put the javascript price variable (1234) as a parameter to the intermediate.php . You may  simply use `<script>window.location.href="intermediate.php?amount=1234";</script>` . In this way you can pass the js variable to a PHP session variable

Comment: okay, got it working and I understand however, theres a lot of configuring I'll need to do with this cheat method, is there any other proper way?

Comment: **Another** way is to use ajax to do the trick (passing JS variable to PHP) , but it is quite different from your original question so I suggest you to ask another question so that we can provide further advice.

Comment: Could you please add onto your current answer with ajax method, that'll be much better.

Comment: As requested, see my revised answer for the ajax method